# [Vue warn]: Property "addBox" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance at <App>

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I'm trying to make it possible to create a new box component which is then added to the screen, however, the error as mentioned in the title appears. I also get another error in the console which goes:

```
[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: new-box
If this is a native custom element, make sure to exclude it from component resolution via compilerOptions.isCustomElement. 
  at <App>
```

Below are the two pieces of relevant code.

App.vue:

```
<template>
    <ul>
        <the-header title="Remember"></the-header>
        <new-box @add-box="addBox"></new-box>
        <box
            name="Box One" ></box>
        <big-box
            title="Big" info="Additional info">
        </big-box>
    </ul>
</template>

<script>
import TheHeader from './components/layouts/TheHeader.vue';
import Box from './components/boxes/Box.vue';
import BigBox from './components/boxes/BigBox.vue';
import NewBox from './components/boxes/NewBox.vue';

export default {
    components: {
        TheHeader,
        Box,
        BigBox,
        NewBox
    },
    data() {
        return {
        boxes: [
            {
            id: "box one",
            name: "name one",
            number: "one"
            }
        ]
        }
    },
    addBox(name, number) {
        const newBox = {
            id: new Date().toISOString(),
            name: name,
            number: number
        };
        this.boxes.push(newBox);
    },
}
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

NewBox.vue:

```
<template>
    <form @submit.prevent="submitData">
        <div>
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" v-model="enteredName" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Box Number</label>
            <input type="text" v-model="enteredNumber" />
        </div>                    
        <div>
            <button>Add Box</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        emits: ['add-box'],
        data() {
            return {
            enteredName: '',
            enteredNumber: ''
            }
        },
        methods: {
            submitData() {
                this.$emit(
                    'add-box', 
                    this.enteredName, 
                    this.enteredNumber
                );
            }
        }
    };
</script>



<style scoped>
#app input {
  font: inherit;
  padding: 0.15rem;
}
#app label {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  width: 7rem;
  display: inline-block;
}
#app form div {
  margin: 1rem 0;
}
</style>
```

The box you can enter data into shows up, along with the button with which you can submit the data, however, nothing quite happens when clicking on it, I was expecting it to work due to the data emitter which I just recently learned about. I am wondering if there should be a @click event in NewBox.vue for the button, but in the example code that inspired what I'm doing here, they didn't have that either and instead also relied on the emit function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your `addBox` method into `methods` block like so:

```
    methods: {
      addBox(name, number) {
          const newBox = {
              id: new Date().toISOString(),
              name: name,
              number: number
          };
          this.boxes.push(newBox);
      },
    },
```

**Edit:**

[Sandbox/Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-ghte9c?file=src/App.vue)

Comment: That makes sense, thank you. However, after changing it, I now get the following, not sure if it's related: DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom/browser-polyfill.js.map: System error: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
log.js?1afd:24 [HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...

Comment: gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom is AdBlock chrome extension, shouldn't have any effect on your app.. Let me see if I can figure out anything else (:

Comment: @Murfy I updated the answer with little reproduction, that I believe is working correctly